How can I disable the back button animation in .net maui
When I want to go back with the back button at the top left or the android phone back button the app makes a swipe animation, which looks not nice and is a little bit buggy.
So how can I disable the backbutton animation for both, the back button at the top left and the android phone back button?

You could start here and see if there is a (object) reference to this particular animation; and if you can disable it. Or show some code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/animation-behavior https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6410

You can edit the animation mode with the Shell.PresentationMode attribute. You can find posible values and examples on the documentation side from Microsoft. Just visit the following link and scroll down to "Set page presentation mode":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-8.0#set-page-presentation-mode
This would be the solution you are searching for:
<ContentPage ...
             Shell.PresentationMode="NotAnimated">
    ...             
</ContentPage>

